# Increasing allocation performance for strings

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management, boost, memory-pool

I ported a Java GC test program to C++ (see the code below) as well as Python. The Java and Python performance is much greater than C++ and I was thinking this was due to all the calls to `new` that have to be done to create the strings each time. I've tried using Boost's `fast_pool_allocator` but that actually worsened performance from 700ms to 1200ms. Am I using the allocator wrong, or is there something else I should be doing?

EDIT: Compiled with `g++ -O3 -march=native --std=c++11 garbage.cpp -lboost_system`. g++ is version 4.8.1
One iteration takes in Python is about 300ms and with Java about 50ms. `std::allocator` gives about 700ms and `boost::fast_pool_allocator` gives about 1200ms.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp>
#include <memory>
//#include <gc/gc_allocator.h>


using namespace std;
#include <sstream>
typedef boost::fast_pool_allocator<char> c_allocator;
//typedef std::allocator<char> c_allocator;
typedef basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, c_allocator> pool_string;
namespace patch {
    template <typename T> pool_string to_string(const T& in) {
        std::basic_stringstream<char, char_traits<char>, c_allocator> stm;
        stm << in;
        return stm.str();
    }
}


#include "mytime.hpp"

class Garbage {
public:
    vector<pool_string> outer;
    vector<pool_string> old;
    const int nThreads = 1;
    //static auto time = chrono::high_resolution_clock();

    void go() {
//        outer.resize(1000000);
        //old.reserve(1000000);
        auto tt = mytime::msecs();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            if (i % 100 == 0) {
                cout << "DOING AN OLD" << endl;
                doOld();
                tt = mytime::msecs();
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < 1000000/nThreads; ++j)
                outer.push_back(patch::to_string(j));

            outer.clear();
            auto t = mytime::msecs();
            cout << (t - tt) << endl;
            tt = t;
        }
    }

    void doOld() {
        old.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000/nThreads; ++i)
            old.push_back(patch::to_string(i));
    }
};

int main() {
    Garbage().go();
}
```

Comment: The [fast_pool_allocator docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost/fast_pool_allocator.html) seem to indicate that you are indeed using it wrong: `pool_allocator` for continuous chunks (e.g. `new char[n]`), `fast_pool_allocators` for single things (e.g. `new char`) .

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this, but I got bored waiting for it to print a number (ie. it was taking a VERY long time)

Comment: @user315118 - There is no mention in your post of compiler used, compiler options used when building your application in terms of optimizations, etc.  If you're going to post code that claims to perform in some unit of time, it is imperative you also post your compiler and options used.  Otherwise we are right to assume you're either using an old compiler, broken compiler, or compiling  without optimizations being fully enabled.

Comment: Are you saying that each loop takes 0.7-1.2s? On my machine, I get around 0.19s with the standard allocator. Either you are running on some fairly slow hardware, or you haven't enabled optimisation.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you. I've updated the question with that information.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yes that is what I meant. I'm optimizing with `-O3 -march=native` and I'm on an AMD FX-6100 processor. What compiler/options are you using?

Comment: I've posted the code and measurements in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you're using a new string stream each time to convert an integer.

Fix it:

```
namespace patch {
    template <typename T> pool_string to_string(const T& in) {
        return boost::lexical_cast<pool_string>(in);
    }
}
```

Now the timings are:

```
DOING AN OLD
0.175462
0.0670085
0.0669926
0.0687969
0.0692518
0.0669318
0.0669196
0.0669187
0.0668962
0.0669185

real    0m0.801s
user    0m0.784s
sys 0m0.016s
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d5223c43b6397e0)**

Full code for reference:

```
#include <boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
//#include <gc/gc_allocator.h>

using string = std::string;

namespace patch {
    template <typename T> string to_string(const T& in) {
        return boost::lexical_cast<string>(in);
    }
}

class Timer
{
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock clock;
    clock::time_point _start;
  public:
    Timer() { reset(); }
    void reset() { _start = now(); }
    double elapsed()
    {
        using namespace std::chrono;
        auto e = now() - _start;
        return duration_cast<nanoseconds>(e).count()*1.0e-9;
    }
    clock::time_point now()
    {
        return clock::now();
    }
};


class Garbage {
    public:
        std::vector<string> outer;
        std::vector<string> old;
        const int nThreads = 1;

        void go() {
            outer.resize(1000000);
            //old.reserve(1000000);
            Timer timer;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                if (i % 100 == 0) {
                    std::cout << "DOING AN OLD" << std::endl;
                    doOld();
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < 1000000/nThreads; ++j)
                    outer.push_back(patch::to_string(j));

                outer.clear();
                std::cout << timer.elapsed() << std::endl;
                timer.reset();
            }
        }

        void doOld() {
            old.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000/nThreads; ++i)
                old.push_back(patch::to_string(i));
        }
};

int main() {
    Garbage().go();
}
```

Comment: As usual, it's the "not where you think it's spending the time" problem... Good spot.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Indeed. As usual it is "profile, profile, profile" (though I used none for this one) :)

Comment: @sehe Great! I hadn't considered the allocation of stringstream. Decalaring it static gives similar results. Although on my computer best performance was still only around 175ms for an iteration. I replaced my timer with yours and now it's about 100ms. So double double emphasis to mats Petersson.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Absolutely... I've been spoiled by my GCed languages haha. I actually made a call-graph, but admitedly took one look at all the templated functions it listed and closed it :/

Comment: Actually, even (or perhaps especially) in GC'd languages, creating a new object every time is a waste of time, and comes back to bite you when it's time to GC the whole thing.

Comment: @sehe I'm a little surprised that performance is better with `std::allocator`, I would have that pooled memory would be advantageous. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: @user315118 declaring it static will also ruin the semantics (you would need to reset the contents, seek to the beginning, clear exception and formatting state etc.). Best not to reinvent the wheel. `boost::lexical_cast` is your friend and it even works with your `pool_string` if you needed. No idea why `std::allocator` is faster, really. Maybe another day. Bedtime :)

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'd believe nothing is better than allocating only once, but if you are going to allocated repeatedly won't the GC be able to do it faster from its pool? I could imagine it not being as bad as long as those allocation don't trigger the GC since when the whole heap is garbage the collection is quicker.

Comment: That's like saying a front wheel drive car is faster than a rear wheel drive car. It's not which wheels drive the car that really matters for speed, but the overall design, power of the engine, if corners are involved the tyres, suspension, etc - front or rear wheel drive is pretty small factors in the whole scheme. I believe this analogy compares fairly well with "garbage collection vs. non-garbage collection". And in my compiler project I'm working on, I just lazily ignore all freeing of memory, and rely on the whole thing being cleaned up at exit. Obviously won't work forever, but...

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't use boost on my machine, I simplified the code to use standard C++11 `to_string` (thus accidentally "fixing" the problem sehe found), and got this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
//#include <gc/gc_allocator.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


class Timer
{
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock clock;
    clock::time_point _start;
    public:
    Timer() { reset(); }
    void reset() { _start = now(); }
    double elapsed()
    {
        using namespace std::chrono;
        auto e = now() - _start;
        return duration_cast<nanoseconds>(e).count()*1.0e-9;
    }
    clock::time_point now()
    {
        return clock::now();
    }
};


class Garbage {
public:
    vector<string> outer;
    vector<string> old;
    const int nThreads = 1;
Timer timer;

    void go() {
//        outer.resize(1000000);
        //old.reserve(1000000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            if (i % 100 == 0) {
                cout << "DOING AN OLD" << endl;
                doOld();
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < 1000000/nThreads; ++j)
                outer.push_back(to_string(j));

            outer.clear();
            cout << timer.elapsed() << endl;
            timer.reset();
        }
    }

    void doOld() {
        old.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000/nThreads; ++i)
            old.push_back(to_string(i));
    }
};

int main() {
    Garbage().go();
}
```

Compiling with:

```
$ g++ -O3 -std=c++11 gc.cpp
$ ./a.out
DOING AN OLD
0.414637
0.189082
0.189143
0.186336
0.184449
0.18504
0.186302
0.186055
0.183123
0.186835
```

clang 3.5 build with source from Friday 18th of April 2014 gives similar results with the same compiler options.

My processor is a AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 965, running at 3.6GHz (if I remember right).

Comment: Thanks for the STL answer. When I actually wrote/debugged the code I was using `cygwin` which has a broken `to_string` implementation, hence the one using stringstreams.

Comment: Yeah, not using windows has it's advantages... ;)